# Swipe and MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading

Tags: ios

When the MKMapView is loaded or reloaded, `MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading` is set so the heading is displayed on the map. But when I swipe the map, the heading disappears and the map rotates to its regular direction. Interestingly, a zoom of the map does not change the heading.

Any information?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I guess after you swipe the map, the map set the UserTrackingMode to MKUserTrackingModeFollow instead of MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading. So the heading tracking is disabled.

You can implement *regionDidChangeAnimated* as follows to solve this problem:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated{
    [mapView setUserTrackingMode:MKUserTrackingModeFollowWithHeading];
}
```